# Can I create and disable multiple onclick events independently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to bind and unbind a second function to an event, without affecting the first function.  For example:

I have a button that has a standard onclick event:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" id="my_button" value="Click Me" />
```

I'd like to bind a second function to it, so that both functions trigger when the button is clicked:

```
$('#my_button').on('click',myOtherFunction());
```

I'd like the second function to only trigger the first time it's clicked, so I'd like to include a line in myOtherFunction() to remove this second binding:

```
$('#my_button').off('click');
```

But I don't want to turn off the original action - myFunction() - and then bind it again, since it seems like that makes the code messier and there's a risk of an error if I want to change the default button click in the future.

Is there a clean way to bind and unbind this second function without affecting the first function?

Comment: [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [`.one` jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/one/) function? It will work as `.on` but deregister the listener once the function has been executed.

```
$('#my_button').one('click',myOtherFunction);
```

Anyway, I'd recommend to bind also the first function in the JS code rather than in the HTML (if you can).

```
$('#my_button')
  .on('click',myFunction)
  .one('click',myOtherFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It wouldn't work for a big general case with multiple conditions for turning off and on, but definitely the best/simplest for what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have proposed is not a good way to go about it.

Bind both functions to the `.on()` callback but use data to make sure it only runs once.

Given functions `one()` and `all()` respectively:

```
$('#my_button').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).data('one-ran')) {
        $(this).data('one-ran', 1);
        one();
    }
    all();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soxtmoo1/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to tackle this problem is to instantiate a click counter:

```
var click = 0
$('#my_button).on('click', function(){
  if (click >= 1){
    // execute code for second function
  }
  // execute first function
  click++

})
```

my JS is a little rusty, but something to this effect